# How to make a matTooltip scrollable in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, tooltip

I tried to make mat tooltip scrollable by assigning following css property in `matTooltipClass`

```
overflow-y: scroll;
max-height: 200px;
```

But this is not working. Can anyone suggest how to make `matToolTip` scrollable in angular

Answer (score 0):

You can go to where your `matTooltip` is used in your template and add a directive name for e.g `allowScroll` next to it. Then in your global .css file:

```
::ng-deep [allowScroll] {
    touch-action: auto !important;
}
```